# Unable to print some array elements in specific format in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

Having the following script to process a file and provide the output in the specific format.
I'm unable to the make the desired output table.

the input

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use diagnostics;

my $temp_M1SLP;
my @temp_M1SLP;

my $start_run = time();

my $header = "CODE           NAME         DST    TY  DAIS             NO    STAT             TM     TMW";
print "$header\n";

open( INFILE, "<Sample1.log" ) or die "Couldn't open file M1SLP.txt\n";
while ( my $line = <INFILE> ) {

    chomp($line);
    @temp_M1SLP = $line;

    if ( $line =~ /^\d-\d+/ ) {
        $temp_M1SLP[0] = ( substr $line, 0,  14 );
        $temp_M1SLP[1] = ( substr $line, 15, 7 );
        $temp_M1SLP[2] = ( substr $line, 28, 5 );
        $temp_M1SLP[3] = ( substr $line, 35, 4 );

        printf( "%-10s", $temp_M1SLP[0] );
        printf( "%-10s", $temp_M1SLP[1] );
        printf( "%-8s",  $temp_M1SLP[2] );
        printf( "%-5s",  $temp_M1SLP[3] );
    }

    next if ( $line =~ /^               DAIS             NO    STAT             TM     TMW/ );

    {
        while ( $line =~ /^\s+\w+/ ) {

            $temp_M1SLP[4] = ( substr $line, 15, 15 );
            $temp_M1SLP[5] = ( substr $line, 32, 4 );
            $temp_M1SLP[6] = ( substr $line, 38, 14 );
            $temp_M1SLP[7] = ( substr $line, 55, 7 );
            $temp_M1SLP[8] = ( substr $line, 62, 5 );

            printf( "%-18s", $temp_M1SLP[4] );
            printf( "%-6s",  $temp_M1SLP[5] );
            printf( "%-8s",  $temp_M1SLP[6] );
            printf( "%-8s",  $temp_M1SLP[7] );
            printf( "%-5s",  "$temp_M1SLP[8]\n" );

            $line = <INFILE>;
        }
    }
}

my $end_run = time();
```

The output file will be in this format

```
CODE           NAME         DST     TY   DAIS                NO    STAT             TM     TMW
2-2017        121CM02       AVA     PP   EP022CM02           1     DM-ACT-AVA              10
2-2017        121CM02       AVA     PP   EP032CM02           1     DM-BAT-BTA       20        
2-2033        119LHR        AVA     PP   HLR3EP03203         1     DM-BAT-BTA            
2-2110        119A1AU       AVA     PP   A1AUEP080           1     DM-BAT-BTA            
2-2110        119A1AU       AVA     PP    A1AUEP090          1     DM-BAT-BTA            
2-2110        119A1AU       AVA     PP   A1AUEP110           1     DM-BAT-BTA            
2-2110        119A1AU       AVA     PP   A1AUEP100           1     DM-BAT-BTA
```

The input file  (Sampel1.txt) is as shown

```
CODE           NAME         DST    TY
2-2017         121CM02      AVA    PP

               DAIS             NO    STAT             TM     TMW
               EP022CM02           1  DM-ACT-AVA              10
               EP032CM02           1  DM-BAT-BTA       20       

2-2033         119LHR       AVA    PP

               DAIS             NO    STAT             TM     TMW
               HLR3EP03203         1  DM-BAT-BTA              

2-2110         119A1AU      AVA    PP

               DAIS             NO    STAT             TM     TMW
               A1AUEP080           1  DM-BAT-BTA              
               A1AUEP090           1  DM-BAT-BTA              
               A1AUEP110           1  DM-BAT-BTA              
               A1AUEP100           1  DM-BAT-BTA
```

But currently, I got the output as following. Please your support to check the code and corrected

```
CODE           NAME         DST    TY  DAIS              NO    STAT               TM     TMW
2-2017        121CM02   AVA     PP   EP022CM02            1  DM-ACT-AVA            10
  EP032CM02            1  DM-BAT-BTA    20        

 2-2033        119LHR    AVA     PP   HLR3EP03203          1  DM-BAT-BTA            
 2-2110        119A1AU   AVA     PP   A1AUEP080            1  DM-BAT-BTA            
    A1AUEP090            1  DM-BAT-BTA            

   A1AUEP110            1  DM-BAT-BTA            

   A1AUEP100            1  DM-BAT-BTA
```

Comment: open (INFILE, "<`Sample1.log`") or die "Couldn't open file `M1SLP.txt`\n"; This is confusion. Which is input and output.

Comment: A proper problem description includes the input data, the program, the output you are getting, the output that you want, and a description of the discrepancy. You will need to give at least a representative sample of your input data that we can use to test.

Comment: The most obvious problem is the line `@temp_M1SLP = $line`, which will simply copy the contents of `$line` into `$temp_M1SLP[0]`. It looks like you may be expecting `$line` to be split on whitespace, which requires `@temp_M1SLP = split ' ', $line`, but you have given too little information for that to be more than a guess.

Comment: Please indent your code to properly reflect the nested blocks. While you may enjoy the challenge of counting braces to understand the structure of your code, it is only polite to make your code as readable as possible if you are asking for help with it. You will *never* see professional code in such a shambles.

Comment: Sorry , I forgot the input file (Sample1.txt)

Comment: Here is the input file

Comment: @Borodin Thank you for formatting the code. I further edited it and removed unused code which was commented-out so we can grasp it easier. If s.o. finds this inappropriate, please rollback my edit (I'm not sure about my edit.)

Comment: Thanks Borodin, Your removed the unused code. Also, I also updated the problem by adding the current output. So, can you check the code now please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution firstly skips all irrelevant lines. When a line starting with `\d-\d+` is found (like `2-2017…`) then the fields CODE, NAME, DST, and TY are only *stored* in global variables. I replaced your array `@temp_M1SLP` with explicit variable names for that.

When a line is found that looks like DAIS, NO, … (identified by a line with a word after whitespace), then the values from the preceding section (CODE, NAME, …) *and* the current values are printed.

My code more or less is a shuffled version of your code. However, I like [Borodin's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39426999/5830574) better as it is much more elegant.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $header = "CODE          NAME      DST     TY   DAIS                NO  STAT          TM     TMW";
print "$header\n";

my ( $code, $name, $dst, $ty );
open( INFILE, "<Sample1.log" ) or die "Couldn't open file Sample1.log\n";
while ( my $line = <INFILE> ) {

    chomp($line);

    # skip header, subheader, and empty lines:
    next if ( $line =~ /^CODE\s+NAME\s+DST\s+TY/ );
    next if ( $line =~ /^\s+DAIS\s+NO\s+STAT\s+TM\s+TMW/ );
    next if ( $line !~ /\S/ );

    # code section found? then remember the values
    # but don't print them yet.
    if ( $line =~ /^\d-\d+/ ) {
        $code = substr( $line, 0,  14 );
        $name = substr( $line, 15, 7 );
        $dst  = substr( $line, 28, 5 );
        $ty   = substr( $line, 35, 4 );
    }

    # line with DAIS, NO, ... found? then print the columns from
    # the code section _and_ the columns of this line:
    if ( $line =~ /^\s+\w+/ ) {
        my $dais = substr( $line, 15, 15 );
        my $no   = substr( $line, 32, 4 );
        my $stat = substr( $line, 38, 14 );
        my $tm   = substr( $line, 55, 7 );
        my $tmw  = substr( $line, 62, 5 );

        printf( "%-10s",  $code );    # from code section
        printf( "%-10s",  $name );    #        "
        printf( "%-8s",   $dst );     #        "
        printf( "%-5s",   $ty );      #        "
        printf( "%-18s",  $dais );    # from current line
        printf( "%-6s",   $no );      #        "
        printf( "%-8s",   $stat );    #        "
        printf( "%-8s",   $tm );      #        "
        printf( "%-5s\n", $tmw );     #        "
    }

}
```

### Output

```
CODE          NAME      DST     TY   DAIS                NO  STAT          TM     TMW
2-2017        121CM02   AVA     PP   EP022CM02            1  DM-ACT-AVA            10   
2-2017        121CM02   AVA     PP   EP032CM02            1  DM-BAT-BTA    20           
2-2033        119LHR    AVA     PP   HLR3EP03203          1  DM-BAT-BTA                 
2-2110        119A1AU   AVA     PP   A1AUEP080            1  DM-BAT-BTA                 
2-2110        119A1AU   AVA     PP   A1AUEP090            1  DM-BAT-BTA                 
2-2110        119A1AU   AVA     PP   A1AUEP110            1  DM-BAT-BTA                 
2-2110        119A1AU   AVA     PP   A1AUEP100            1  DM-BAT-BTA
```

Comment: @Tatman Please don't edit _my_ answer to post _your_ attempts. You wrote you tried to simulate my code and got an error. That is because you kept your logical mistakes and just moved the `print` statements around.

Comment: Sorry, I'll not edit your code. I just tried to know where is my fault. As you said, my logic still wrong. Can you show my why.?

Comment: @Tatman One problem is that you use two loops to read your file. The inner loop reads up to EOF and `$line` becomes `undef` and the `while ( $line =~ /^\s+\w+/ ) {` then fails. Also, you reset `@temp_M1SLP = $line;` in each outer loop to something useless which voids all the variables already stored in `@temp_M1SLP[0..3]` (from the previous iteration). Drop the `@temp_M1SLP = $line;` and check for definedness of `$line` in _both_ loops, not just the outer one.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support.  You gave me very good support . You helped me 2 times. The 1st one when you provide me a code with same way that I programmed my code. The 2nd that, Your last comments show me my faults. And I corrected my code based on your comments and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I would have preferred to see more effort to solve this yourself, in particular I don't see why I had to format your Perl code for you after asking you to do it

However, here is a solution to get this question out of the way

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $header = "CODE           NAME         DST    TY  DAIS             NO    STAT             TM     TMW";

# Construct the printf format string to reproduce the header line spacing
#
my $format = do {

    my @start;
    push @start, $-[0] while $header =~ /\S+/g;

    my @sizes = map { $start[$_+1] - $start[$_] } 0 .. $#start-1;

    join("", map { "%-${_}s" } @sizes, "") . "\n";
};

printf $format, split ' ', $header;

open my $fh, '<', 'Sample1.log' or die qq{Couldn't open file "Sample1.log" for input: $!};

my @head;

while ( <$fh> ) {

    # Example:
    # CODE           NAME         DST    TY
    # 2-2017         121CM02      AVA    PP

    if (/^\d+-\d+/) {
        @head = unpack 'A15 A13 A7 A*';
    }

    # Example:
    #                DAIS             NO    STAT             TM     TMW
    #                EP022CM02           1  DM-ACT-AVA              10
    #                EP032CM02           1  DM-BAT-BTA       20       

    elsif ( /\d/ ) {

        my @tail = unpack '@15 A17 A6 A17 A7 A*';
        $tail[1] += 0;

        printf $format, @head, @tail;
    }
}
```

#### output

```
CODE           NAME         DST    TY  DAIS             NO    STAT             TM     TMW
2-2017         121CM02      AVA    PP  EP022CM02        1     DM-ACT-AVA              10
2-2017         121CM02      AVA    PP  EP032CM02        1     DM-BAT-BTA       20     
2-2033         119LHR       AVA    PP  HLR3EP03203      1     DM-BAT-BTA              
2-2110         119A1AU      AVA    PP  A1AUEP080        1     DM-BAT-BTA              
2-2110         119A1AU      AVA    PP  A1AUEP090        1     DM-BAT-BTA              
2-2110         119A1AU      AVA    PP  A1AUEP110        1     DM-BAT-BTA              
2-2110         119A1AU      AVA    PP  A1AUEP100        1     DM-BAT-BTA
```

Comment: Very elegant solution! I always forget about `pack/unpack`. I didn't investigate further, but this might also be a job for Perl's [`format/write`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlform.html) facility. I never used it seriously, though.

Comment: @PerlDog: I don't like `format`, mainly because I always have to read up again how to use it, and it will never *quite* do what I want. [Perl6::Form](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl6::Form) is an implementation of the Perl 6 `form` operator, which is far better.

Comment: @Borodin . Thank You very much.  As a beginner in Perl. I learn many things from your code, Especially about (unpack).   I still have one query. Why you used ( $tail[1] += 0; ). It tried to remove it from the code, and the code working fine. Can you explain please?

Comment: @Tatman: That is the numeric `NO` field which has leading spaces in the input data. Adding zero to it simply converts it into an integer value so that `printf` can align it properly. If you look at the output without that statement you will see that the values aren't aligned properly under the heading as you requested.

Comment: @Borodin Based on your profile, you have skills on AWK. I have posted a query for AWK script, because i tried to get the output in a specific format. But i couldn't.  If have time and take a look for it , I'll be appreciated. The problem is in the title      (AWK: Unable to get the output desired based on my file using (substr & Regex)).